# "tenant is temporarily unavailable due to server patching" fault while trying to integrate with workday soap api

Tags: workday-api

While trying to integrate with workday soap api I'm keep recieving the following error: `<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.authenticationError</faultcode> <faultstring>tenant is temporarily unavailable due to server patching</faultstring>`.

I failed to find any relevant information regard this issue. Anyone know what the meaning of this kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

That error is returned not only during server patching but also when there is an error with the tenant's name. Make sure that you're spelling the tenant correctly *which includes case*. **ThisTenant** is not the same as **thistenant**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

one of the major reason of this error is the format of username you provide in header. the correct one should be `username@tenant_name`

Comment: Any real example so far?